# Is it possible to export the total number of http requests as a Prometheus metric?

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

I've set up Spring Boot Actuator to export Prometheus metrics. By default, it seems to only log the duration of requests.

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/api/tracks",} 2.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/api/tracks",} 0.049413907
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="UNKNOWN",} 2.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="UNKNOWN",} 0.085091653
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="CLIENT_ERROR",status="401",uri="UNKNOWN",} 10.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="CLIENT_ERROR",status="401",uri="UNKNOWN",} 0.012306617
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="CLIENT_ERROR",status="404",uri="/**",} 1.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="CLIENT_ERROR",status="404",uri="/**",} 0.002903253
```

Is there a way to export a metric for how many requests the service has received, just like it does for duration?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the ever increasing totals, just use the counter metric name as the Prometheus query:

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count
```

But what you'd rather want is a count during a specific interval:

```
sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1m])) # without limiting to specific tags
sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="$application", instance="$instance"}[1m])) # limit on specifically tagged metrics (using Grafana template variables here)
```

Instead of hardcoding the interval (here "1m"), you can also use [Grafana provided ones](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/template-variables/#use-interval-and-range-variables).